# Blinding to mask private key operations

Tags: cryptography, blinding

Blinding is often used to mask private key operations when the underlying problem is integer factorization. For example, its used in both RSA and Rabin-Williams signature schemes. This presumes integer operations are not constant time.

I have two questions:

- Is blinding used in schemes other than integer factorization?
- Are there other options to guard the private key from timing attacks?

Comment: Could/should have been asked on the crypto site...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - done: [Blinding to mask private key operations](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27139). I'll delete this question soon.